# почему не работает promise nodeJS с gtts. Всё равно сначало работает всё в .then, а потом в родителе

Tags: node.js, асинхронность, promise

У меня есть вот такой код, я искренне не понимаю почему промис работает не корректо, вроде я всё делаю верно, но оно не работает, я пробовал и без async await -- получается тоже самое

```
const gtts = require('node-gtts')('ru');
const color = require('colors');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const speech = (congratulations) => {
    var filepath = path.join(__dirname, `./voice.mp3`);
    
    gtts.save(filepath, congratulations, () => {
        console.log('Создание трека поздравления выполнено ' + color.green('УСПЕШНО'));
    })
}

const sendmes = () => {
    return new Promise(res => {
        speech('Поздравляю')
        res()
    })    
}


const one = async () =>{
    await sendmes();
    console.log('Привет')
}

one()
```

Консоль выдаёт следующее:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\bothappy>npm start

> bothappy@1.0.0 start
> node index.js

headers {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'
}
Привет
Создание трека поздравления выполнено УСПЕШНО
```

**"Привет" должен отображаться после "Успешного создания файла"
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, что я делаю не так?**

Comment: Потому что speech не является промисом и потому что вы никак не дожидаетесь завершения работы gtts.save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const speech = (congratulations) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const filepath = path.join(__dirname, `./voice.mp3`);
    gtts.save(filepath, congratulations, (err) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Создание трека поздравления выполнено ' + color.green('УСПЕШНО'));
        resolve(filepath);
      } else {
        reject(err);
      }
    })
  });
}

const one = async () => {
  await speech('Поздравляю');
  console.log('Привет')
}

one()
```